# PowerPoint + VSTO dynamically changing context menu

Tags: c#, vba, vsto, contextmenu, powerpoint

I want to add some buttons (and maybe other types of controls - I am not sure now) to contextmenu, but only if some conditions are met. So, there is available Application.WindowBeforeRightClick event, but it fires only when I click on slide, not when click on some shapes.

So far I added some xml as a ribbon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuShape">
      <button id="button1" label="button1"/>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuObjectsGroup">
      <button id="button2" label="Align vertical axes" onAction="AlignXAxis"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
      <button id="button3" label="Align horizontal axes" onAction="AlignYAxis"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
      <button id="button4" label="Align scale" onAction="MaxScale"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
      <button id="button5" label="Add legend" onAction="Legend"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
      <button id="button6" label="Adjust chart width" onAction="AdjustWidth"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
      <button id="button7" label="Adjust chart height" onAction="AdjustHeight"  getVisible="ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

And code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.WindowBeforeRightClick += new PPT.EApplication_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(Application_WindowBeforeRightClick);
    ribbon= (Ribbon1)CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject();
}

void Application_WindowBeforeRightClick(PPT.Selection Sel, ref bool Cancel)
{
    PPT.Selection selection= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
    if (selection.Type==PPT.PpSelectionType.ppSelectionShapes)
    {
        if (selection.ShapeRange.HasChart==MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
            ribbon.TurnOnChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to check type of selected shapes, hide/show/add/remove controls and then show proper context menu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Application_WindowSelectionChange` event will fire when you right click on a shape. You can check the type of shape (or any other critera) within that event handler.

In order to update the context menu, you need to invalidate the ribbon. This calls your `ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility` callback and updates the visibility of your context menu items based on the criteria. You will likely need to provide which critera has been met to the `ChangeCMObjectsGroupVisibility` callback using global variables.